# Best way to get an element using its id from an array in Angular

Tags: arrays, angular, typescript

Angular: I have a variable, `myNumber = 5` 
and an array of objects, ids and names.
`nameArray: Nameset[] = [];`

The array looks like this:

```
0: {id: 1, name: "Jim"}
1: {id: 3, name: "Bob"}
2: {id: 5, name: "Carl"}
```

What is the best way to the the matching name from the array where `id === myNumber`

I always use a forEach loop like this, but is this the best way?

```
getName(myNumber) {
    let helper = '';
    this.nameArray.forEach(aNameset => {
      if (aNameset.id === myNumber) {
        helper = aNameset.name;
      }
    })
    return helper;
  }
```

Comment: There are 2 ways.
1 - change your array to this:

nameArray = {
  1: "Jim",
  3: "Bob"
  5: "Carl"
}

and just call `this.nameArray[myNumber]`
2 - replace getName with 
`return this.nameArray.find(el => el.id === myNumber).map(el => el.name);`

Comment: I am using your second way. Works just fine. Thanks for your help.